# Stop reusing the tableview cell for video

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've to play a video on table view cell but don't want reuse should happen for video cell because it will recreate the video again.

I tried to cache the cell in array and load from an array if exist but that is making some issue when view pops to the previous view.

The video was keep playing even though it was removed.

```
AVTableViewCell *cachedCell = [self.cellList objectForKey:indexPath];
if (cachedCell) {
    return cachedCell;
} else {
    AVTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AVTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configCell:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (section == 1) {
    [self.cellList setObject:(AVTableViewCell *)cell forKey:indexPath];
  }
}
```

Below code I'm removing the video before pop to view controller but still video or audio is playing sometime.

```
- (IBAction)btnBackTapped:(id)sender {

    // To Avoid the re-using video cell, implemented cache so make sure it got removed before going back to the previous screen.

    AVTableViewCell *cachedCell = [self.cellList objectForKey:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
    if (cachedCell)
    {
        if (cachedCell.isJWVideo) {
            [cachedCell.player stop];
            [cachedCell.player.view removeFromSuperview];
            cachedCell.player = nil;
        } else {
            [cachedCell.ytPlayerView stopVideo];
            [cachedCell.ytPlayerView clearVideo];
            cachedCell.ytPlayerView = nil;
        }

        [self.cellList removeAllObjects];
        self.cellList = nil;
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

is there any other technique to play a video on table view cell without reusing? because when I do scroll up and down it's blocking scroll view to load video again.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against cacheing table cells - you'll likely end up with all sorts of problems.

In `AVTableViewCell` you should override the `prepareForReuse` method and set `self.ytPlayerView = nil` there.

That way, freshly re-used table cells are handed to your tableview code blank, so they cannot try to re-load their old video player view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I’ve tried that part already but what is happening, it’s recreating the video again when cell re use happen which means I’ve to wait to see the video which is already been loaded because of reuse it got removed and loading it again.

`- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];    
    if (self.isJWVideo) {
        [self.jwPlayer stop];
        self.jwPlayer = nil;
    } else {
        [self.ytPlayerView stopVideo];
        self.ytPlayerView = nil;
    }
}`

Can you tell me is there anything wrong in above code.

Comment: It looks OK, but I can't really tell from here. Have you looked at using `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to stop video and remove the player? That's the official way to detect when cells are removed from a table.